# Get frequency of item occurrences in a column as percentage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, percentage

I want to get a percentage of a particular value in a df column. Say I have a df with (col1, col2 , col3, gender)  gender column has values of M, F, or Other. I want to get the percentage of M, F, Other values in the df.

I have tried this, which gives me the number M, F, Other instances, but I want these as a percentage of the total number of values in the df.

```
df.groupby('gender').size()
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Use `value_counts` with `normalize=True`:

```
df['gender'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

The result is a fraction in range (0, 1]. We multiply by 100 here in order to get the %.

Answer (score 12):

If you do not need to look `M` and `F` values other than `gender` column then, may be you can try using `value_counts()` and `count()` as following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender':['M','M','F', 'F', 'F']})
# Percentage calculation
(df['gender'].value_counts()/df['gender'].count())*100
```

Result:

```
F    60.0
M    40.0
Name: gender, dtype: float64
```

---

Or, using `groupby`:

```
(df.groupby('gender').size()/df['gender'].count())*100
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's say there are 200 values out of which 120 are categorized as M and 80 as F

**1)**

```
df['gender'].value_counts()

 output:

 M=120
 F=80
```

**2)**

```
df['gender'].value_counts(Normalize=True)

  output:

  M=0.60
  F=0.40
```

**3)**

```
df['gender'].value_counts(Normalize=True)*100 #will convert output to percentages

  output:

  M=60
  F=40
```

Comment: its `normalize=True` instead of `Normalize` docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Answer (score 0):

## finding the percentage of target variation to chenck imbalance/not.

```
g = data[Target_col_Y]
df = pd.concat([g.value_counts(),              
g.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)],axis=1,keys=('counts','percentage'))

print (df)
```

counts  percentage

0   36548   88.734583

1    4640   11.265417

## finding the maximum in the columns percentage here, to check how much #imbalance there

```
df1=df.diff(periods=1,axis=0)
difvalue=df1[[list(df1.columns)[-1]]].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('(Gender Male= 0):\n {}%'.format(100 - round(df['Gender'].mean()*100, 2)))
print('(Gender Female=1):\n{}%'.format(round(df['Gender'].mean()*100, 2)))
```