# Calculating the percentage of a category in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a dataframe `train` and I have filtered a certain number of rows from the `train` dataframe to form the `promoted` dataframe:

```
print(train.department.value_counts(),'\n')
promoted=train[train.is_promoted==1]
print(promoted.department.value_counts())
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Sales & Marketing    16840
Operations           11348
Technology            7138
Procurement           7138
Analytics             5352
Finance               2536
HR                    2418
Legal                 1039
R&D                    999
Name: department, dtype: int64

Sales & Marketing    1213
Operations           1023
Technology            768
Procurement           688
Analytics             512
Finance               206
HR                    136
R&D                    69
Legal                  53
Name: department, dtype: int64
```

I want to display how much percentage of each category of the column department has appeared from the `train` in the `promoted` dataframe,i.e Instead of the numbers 1213,1023,768,688,etc. I should get a percentage such as: 1213/16840*100=7.2,etc. Please note that I don't want a normalized value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
promoted.department.value_counts()/train.department.value_counts()*100
```

It should give you the desired output:

```
Sales & Marketing    7.2030
Operations           9.0148
Technology          10.7593 
.....                 ...
Name: department, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What if I want the result in descending order?

Comment: @Ronith Try `(promoted.department.value_counts()/train.department.value_counts()*100)[::-1]`. Experiment with `ascending` parameter in [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get the desired result.

Comment: `(promoted.department.value_counts()/train.department.value_counts()*100)[::-1]` doesn't work, and can you explain how I can use `ascending` parameter for two different columns of two different dataframes.

Comment: Yeah. I know that ascending=False will give me values in descending order, but I wanted to know how to get the output given in this answer in descending order.

Comment: @Ronith It seems you just need `(promoted.department.value_counts()/train.department.value_counts()*100).sort_values(ascending=False)`?

Answer (score 2):

Found a better answer at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50558594/4106458

It suggests to use normalize=True named parameter for value_counts() method

For your scenario, the code would be :

```
promoted.department.value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Example has a toy dataset, but the key idea is simply dividing one value count by the other.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'department': list(range(10)) * 100,
    'is_promoted': np.random.randint(0, 2, size =  1000)
})

# Slice out promoted data.

data_promoted = data[data['is_promoted'] == 1]

# Calculate share of each department that is present in data_promoted.

data_promoted['department'].value_counts().sort_index() / data['department'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

Gives:

```
0    0.50
1    0.52
2    0.45
3    0.54
4    0.41
5    0.50
6    0.45
7    0.52
8    0.60
9    0.52
Name: department, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/home/spaceman/my_work/Most-Recent-Cohorts-Scorecard-Elements.csv")
df=df[['STABBR']] #each values is appearing in dataframe with multiple 
#after that i got  
CA    717
TX    454
NY    454
FL    417
PA    382
OH    320
IL    280
MI    189
NC    189
.........
.........

print df['STABBR'].value_counts(normalize=True) #returns the relative 
frequency by dividing all values by the sum of values
CA    0.099930
TX    0.063275
NY    0.063275
FL    0.058118
PA    0.053240
OH    0.044599
IL    0.039024
MI    0.026341
NC    0.026341
..............
..............
```