# Getting percent occurence of each item in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column `Reason` with 89 entries, consisting of `a,b,c,d,e`. I'm trying to find the % occurrence of each Reason.

Now, I'm doing `np.sum(df.eval('Reason == "a"').groupby(keys).sum())*(100/89)` for each `Reason` separately. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50558594/4909087 `df['Reason'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.