# How can I set up the pivot_table in pandas to count total values and derive the percentage?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I am a beginner of python and pandas.
I am practicing the pivot_table.

This is the Data I have made for the practice.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the source DataFrame is as follows:

```
    Id Status
0  747   good
1  587    bad
2  347   good
3  709   good
```

I think that *pivot* is here a bad choice.
To **count** total values, a more natural solution is rather *value_counts*.
Together with setting proper column names, the code can be:

```
res = df.Status.value_counts().reset_index()
res.columns = ['Status', 'total']
```

So far, we have only totals. To count percentages, another instruction
is needed:

```
res['percentage'] = res.total / res.total.sum()
```

The result, for my data, is:

```
  Status  total  percentage
0   good      3        0.75
1    bad      1        0.25
```

Comment: ```.value_counts(normalize=True)``` will be better fit here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50558594/11610186